# How to create commentsExtended.xml,commentsExtensible,commentdIds file for word in apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to copy comment from one docx file to other in poi, I tried creating comments.xml and copied comment to other word file but reply comment is created as separate comment. When I analyzed xml files, the relationship for comment and its reply is mentioned in commentsExtended.xml file. Can anyone please me how to create such file as relation for that file is not mentioned in XWPFRelation.

Comment: `Apache poi`'s `ooxml` part was developed from `XSD` definitions of `Microsoft Office 2007` and currently always is on that state. But `commentsExtended.xml` was introduced in 2012. So it was not part of 2007 `ooxml` definitions. So `apache poi` has no classes to handle this until now. So only way would be processing the `XML` directly on a very low level.

Comment: Can you please give any sample code to handle xml directly on a very low level or is there any other alternative to copy comments from one docx to other. My requirement is to merge many docx file into single docx for which I am in need of copying comments along with that